# Toggle Open/Close JS function

Tags: javascript

I've never posted here before, and I'm hoping you can help me. I have a js function that on click will toggle display and hiding a paragraph. However, I need to nest them upon one another. In other words:

1) Some text here //Click to open

```
 2)This text opens upon click //Click to open

      3)This text opens upon click.
```

They way I have it written now, clicking 1 opens 2 up, but clicking 2 closes everything. I'm just learning JS now, so I'm now the best with it, so I'm hoping the pros here can help me. Here's what my function looks like now http://pastebin.com/ZUzp1pUJ Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: You seem to have jQuery loaded on that example yet you aren't making use of it, it will make your life a lot easier. If you're already loading it into your page you really should take advantage of it.

Comment: Also, here's a little [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VGcZ8/) you may find useful.

Comment: If you happen to have a clear example on the web, of what you would like this toggle sequence to look like, you would get a faster answer too.

Comment: Hello first poster. In the future, try to insert and format your code directly into your post. Eventually, that link will expire, and the question will be totally useless for someone with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you included jQuery in your HTML but you're not using it anywhere, I'll assume you're new to jQuery and willing to use it.

Here's what you do.

First you should read up on the [jQuery Reference](http://api.jquery.com/). It is extremely useful.

The things you need to give extra attention to are these:

- [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) - use $('.myClass') instead of getElementsByClassName
- [jQuery Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) - or any of it's companions (slideToggle, fadeToggle) to do exactly what you asked for.
- and as to your question - [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) - which allows you to trigger only the toggle that you clicked and stop the event from bubbling up through the dom. (and not to trigger it's parents.)

These three combined should do the work. Good luck.